No cookie in request headers from tRPC client received at tRPC server
I try to get cookies of the request from tRPC client using this context.ts of tRPC server:
import { IncomingMessage, ServerResponse } from 'http';
export async function createContext({ req, res }: { req: IncomingMessage; res: ServerResponse }) {

    console.log(req.headers);
    
    le user = null;
    return {
        user,
    };
}
export type Context = Awaited<ReturnType<typeof createContext>>;

tRPC server is hosted under http://localhost:2022
and I send requests to it from tRPC client at http://localhost:3000 like
import { createTRPCProxyClient, httpBatchLink } from '@trpc/client';
const trpcClient = createTRPCProxyClient<AppRouter>({
    links: [
        httpBatchLink({
            url: 'http://localhost:2022',
            fetch(url, options) {
                return fetch(url, {
                  ...options,
                  credentials: 'include',
                });
            },
        }),
    ],
});
export default trpcClient;

and there are cookies with HttpOnly and SameSite=Lax at http://localhost:3000, but they are not sent to tRPC server as I don't see any cookie in headers in console.log(req.headers), what I see is only
{
  host: 'localhost:2022',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  accept: '*/*',
  'accept-language': '*',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'user-agent': 'node',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate'
}

I use standalone tRPC server with working cors like
createHTTPServer({
    middleware: cors({
        origin: 'http://localhost:3000',
        credentials: true
    }),
    router: appRouter,
    createContext,
}).listen(2022);

when I go at http://localhost:2022 in browser, I see the cookies
how to receive cookies at the tRPC server?
